# Same prefix endpoint but two different Controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I remember working on a project made in Django where you could create routes that could be given a prefix and then include another URL file for the rest of the endpoint.

```py
api_patterns= [
  url('foo/', include(foo.urls)),
  url('bar/', include(bar.urls)),
]

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'api/', include(api_patterns)),
]
```

This implementation would result in endpoints `/api/foo/` and `/api/bar/` and these endpoints would live in separate directories with separate url files.

## The question is whether we can implement something equivalent to **Spring Boot**.

I know you can add the prefix to the `@RequestMapping` on all the files.
But in my current project, we have a lot of controllers that start from the same route prefix and then, later on, differ from each other.

```java
// Foo controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "api/foo")
public class FooController {

  @GetMapping(path = "")
  // Endpoint to /api/foo
}

// Bar controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "api/bar")
public class BarController {

  @GetMapping(path = "")
  // Endpoint to /api/bar
}

// Tar controller by foo
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "api/foo/tar")
public class TarController {

  @GetMapping(path = "")
  // Endpoint to /api/foo/tar
}
```

The endpoint would then look like this `/api/foo`, `/api/bar`, and `/api/foo/tar`.

How can I prevent the repeated path prefix on all the files?

*This routing might be a bad practice for working with API endpoint, I also think that this could be prevented, and that is why I'm asking as a junior developer to try to improve and show responsibility at my first job.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best practice would be something like

```
/**
 * Class for String constants to use in the application
 */
public final class WebConstants {

   public static final String API = "api";
   ...other constants

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = WebConstants.API + "/foo")
public class FooController {

  @GetMapping
  // serve something for /api/foo

  @GetMapping(path = "/tar")
  // serve something for /api/foo/tar

}

// Bar controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = WebConstants.API + "/bar")
public class BarController {

  @GetMapping
  // Serve something for /api/bar
}
```

Comment: I can see this implementation happening and why this could be good practice for providing the path. With this implementation, the endpoint is gathered in one place, and when the application gets big, the debugging starts from that place other than having to inspect many areas.

As the application gets bigger and some path have the same start of endpoint but different usage the path could then be replaced with a constant that before was only a constant together with a string path.

`WebConstants.API + "/foo"` becomes `WebConstant.API_FOO`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to smash the controllers with the same endpoint beginning.
I'd suggest you to remain this annotation `@RequestMapping(path = "/api/foo")` and just insert inside that class the methods with `@GetMapping(path = "/tar")`. And other methods could have prefix tar: `"/tar/example"`.

But if there are lots of methods starting with this prefix `/api/foo/tar` and the class `FooController` begins to be big enough, it's nice to keep them separately.

Comment: I agree with you. It is always good to start on a smaller scale and incrementally improve the code. And this can, of course, be implemented with the suggestion from @Panagiotis Bougioukos

Answer (score 0):

You can have an interface like below:

`import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public interface BaseController {
}`

Then every individual controller class can implement the interface like below:

`public class FooController implements BaseController {
  @GetMapping(path = "/foo")
  // Endpoint to /api/foo
}`

Provided it is possible to change every controller class.

Comment: I could see this work for a project that is not that big and have a complex endpoint router. The issue here would be that the following prefix on the next controller would need to add that same path on all the following endpoints in the fooController. Every Mapping gets a start of `path = "/foo/*"`

Comment: And on inspection, this would result in not being able to add a `RequestMapping` annotation on the class as it would overwrite the request mapping in the interface.